# How can I get more than one GET parameter by using switch/case in php?

Tags: php, database, loops, get, switch-statement

I'm pretty new to programming and currently working on a video game database thingy. I'm stuck at a point at which I want to filter my entries with the "GET" method. It all works fine until I want to search after **multiple parameters** for the main issue is to go through my switch/case statement **multiple** times. So here's the code:

```
    $columnName = NULL;
    $searchValue = NULL;

    switch ($_GET) {
    case isset($_GET['name']):
        $columnName = "games.name";
        $searchValue = $_GET['name'];
        break;
    case isset($_GET['developer']):
        $columnName = "developer.name";
        $searchValue = $_GET['developer'];
        break;
    case isset($_GET['device']):
        $columnName = "devices.name";
        $searchValue = $_GET['device'];
        break;
    case isset($_GET['company']):
        $columnName = "company.name";
        $searchValue = $_GET['company'];
        break;
    case isset($_GET['medium']):
        $columnName = "medium.name";
        $searchValue = $_GET['medium'];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if ($columnName !== null && $searchValue !== null) {
    $selectStatement .= " WHERE " . $columnName . " LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%'";
}
```

The variable *$selectStatement* is the selection statement for my database entries, but i thought it would not be helpful to post it in it's entirety.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm surprised that I got so many answers after just a few minutes, thank you so much! 
But I tried every single of your answers and none is really working for me. For example, if I search for two parameters now, it only recognizes the last one. 
In this example 
`http://localhost/index.php?developer=ubisoft&medium=disc` 
it only shows me the medium, but not the developer...

Comment: use multiple `if` statements instead of `switch`

Comment: I guess if you dont use "break", then it will check each parameter. But then you will need to change value and column values in order to include all the parameters.

Comment: @MrKiwey updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

You should use if statement for multiple conditions or do not use break statement (not recommended)

**Working demo with static GET values**: https://eval.in/868873

```
if ($_GET) {
    if( isset($_GET['name']))
    {       
        $columnName[] = "games.name";
        $searchValue[] = $_GET['name'];
    }
    if( isset($_GET['developer']))
    {       
        $columnName[] = "developer.name";
        $searchValue[] = $_GET['developer'];
    }
    if( isset($_GET['device']))
    {       
        $columnName[] = "devices.name";
        $searchValue[] = $_GET['device'];
    }
    if( isset($_GET['company']))
    {       
        $columnName[] = "company.name";
        $searchValue[] = $_GET['company'];
    }
    if( isset($_GET['medium']))
    {       
        $columnName[] = "medium.name";
        $searchValue[] = $_GET['medium'];
    }
}
```

Loop through `columnName`

```
$selectStatement = '';
if ($columnName !== null && $searchValue !== null) {
    $length = count($columnName);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) 
            $selectStatement .= " WHERE " . $columnName[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $searchValue[$i] . "%'";
        else
            $selectStatement .= " AND " . $columnName[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $searchValue[$i] . "%'";           
    }
}

echo $selectStatement;
```

for `?developer=ubisoft&medium=disc`

Output:

```
WHERE developer.name LIKE '%ubisoft%' AND medium.name LIKE '%disc%'
```

Comment: Also added demo link with static GET params

Answer (score 0):

why do you use switch/case statement? It is suitable for searching one occurence of element in your elements set. Just use if statement. It would look like following:

```
$columns = array();

if(isset($_GET["column1"])) {
    $columns []= $_GET["column1"];      
}

if(isset($_GET["column2"])) {
    $columns []= $_GET["column2"];      
}

$columnsString = implode(",", $columns);

// You will get string like "column1,column2"
// And you can make the same thing with your WHERE statements
```

Answer (score 0):

switch is not ideal to use for your case.

you can have an IF ELSE condition

```
if ( isset($_GET['name']) ){
   $columnName = "games.name";
   $searchValue = $_GET['name'];
}
elseif( isset($_GET['developer']) ) {
   $columnName = "developer.name";
   $searchValue = $_GET['developer'];
}
elseif(){

}
and so on....
```

Another way is you can have an array to map your parameter to column name.

```
$_GET['type'] --> this can be your name, developer, medium, device, company...
$_GET['value'] --> your value for name or developer or medium....

$mapping = [
  'name' => 'games.name',
  'developer' => 'developer.name',
  'device' => 'device.name',
  'medium' => 'medium.name'
];

$columnName  = $mapping[$_GET['type']];
$searchValue = $_GET['value'];

$selectStatement .= " WHERE " . $columnName . " LIKE '%" . $searchValue . "%'";
```